# Row-fn with a parameter in clojure

Tags: function, parameters, clojure, row

I have two functions, one of them gets the data from the database

```
(defn getSimilarTexts[id]
   (j/query mysql-db
    ["select * from news"]
    :row-fn printText
    ))
```

And the other one should call a different function, like this:

```
(defn printText[row id]
  (oneWord (row :id) (row :title) (row :text) id))
```

but I don't know how to write the `:row-fn printText` line, so that the `printText` function gets the `id` parameter.

Is there any way you can do that?

Comment: Not related to your problem but important all the same (IMO): the naming convention in Clojure is using lower case letters separating words by a dash. This means instead of `getSimilarTexts` you would write `get-similiar-texts`. Additionally I would also lose the `get` and just name the function `similar-news`.

Comment: Why do you need the function `print-text` to get the `id` as an additional parameter if you can just get it from `row` as you are already doing it `(:id row)`?

Comment: it's not the id of the row I am using

Comment: `:row-fn #(printText % id)` should do it

Comment: @tazrmi I see, then I would do what cfrick suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a closure.  Here's an example using an anonymous function:

```
(defn getSimilarTexts[id]
   (j/query mysql-db
    ["select * from news"]
    :row-fn (fn [row]
              (printText row id))))
```

Here the `id` variable within the anonymous function will be bound to the `id` passed to `getSimilarTexts`.